# Can the principle of helium ion microscopes be generalized to heavier noble gasses for suitable substances?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, laser, microscopy, ions

I have heard helium ion microscopes offer extremely high resolution of features due to the shorter debroglie wavelength of the helium atoms.

Naturally I was curious if anyone has built something using heavier noble gases like a neon ion beam. I suppose such beams could be more likely to damage a lot of materials, at least according to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_helium_ion_microscope) where it explicitly states "In contrast to other ion beams, there is no discernible sample damage due to relatively light mass of the helium ion." but I was curious if for a given noble gas $N$ , there is a set of materials that won't be damaged which could then be photographed using an ion beam made of $N$ and if the resolution of such a microscope accordingly higher?

If, this is possible, then in theory how much smaller can these images get? Would it be possible to get into single picometer scale images?

Comment: Given that Zeiss Orion machines run He or Ne already, it clearly can be done.

Comment: Interesting! so are the neon based machines even higher resolution than helium on some substances?

Comment: There seems to be a parameter called "spot-size" which is smaller for the helium compared to the neon flavor https://www.ornl.gov/content/zeiss-orion-nanofab-helium-and-neon-ion-microscope I'm going to look into what that is

Comment: The Helium ion beam achieves a 0.5 nm resolution @ an energy of: 30kV while the Neon ion beam achieves a 1.9 nm resolution @ 25kV. It's not clear to me if the Neon beam at 30kV would be of finer resolution than the helium since they aren't being compared at the same energy levels and higher energy should reduce the wavelength

Comment: You should calculate the de Broglie wavelength of either and see if it has any relation to the actual resolution. Effective source size and land aberrations may also have a large impact.